# How to making edges from dataframe in NX

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, social-networking

I have a dataframe that contains movies, actors names etc. And it has 41k rows.
[image]

I'm planning to make a graph from NX library and I want to use actors as nodes, and make edges if they are played in a same movie. I tried to make it dataframe and do it with for loops but I couldn't. Can you help me?

Edit: I want to make a graph like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, please add some code that you have done to plot graph.

Comment: Only thing I could do is read the data as df. Tried to make groupby the movie names but unfortunately, I couldn't do as I wanted and it does not look proper. @Hamed_gibago .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, let's try something like this using networkx and itertools libraries:

```
from itertools import tee
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': [*'AAABBCCCDD'],
                  'Actor':[1,2,3,2,5,7,8,9,10,8]})

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


G = nx.Graph()
for _, s in df.groupby('Movie'):
    if s.shape[0] > 1:
        [G.add_edge(*i) for i in pairwise(s['Actor'])]
    else:
        G.add_node(s['Actor'].iloc[0])
        
nx.draw_networkx(G)

[list(i) for i in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

Output:

[image]

And, actor groups:

[[1, 2, 3, 5], [8, 9, 10, 7]]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.